# Using Cauchy's Estimate for Lower Bound of Entire Function

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, entire-functions

> Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function and
>   assume there are positive real numbers $L$, $M$ and $N$ such that $$
>  L|z|^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq f(z) \leq M+N|z|^\frac{3}{2} $$ for all z. 
>   Prove that there are complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
>   $\beta \neq 0$ and $f(z) = \alpha + \beta z$ for all z.

I understand why $f(z) = \alpha + \beta z$ for all z. Namely by Cauchy's Estimate,
$$
|f''(0)| \leq \frac{2(M+N|z|^{\frac{3}{2}})}{R^2}
$$
for all $|z| = R$ now letting $R \rightarrow \infty $. we get $f''(z) = 0$

However I am not seeing how to use the lowerbound of $f(z)$ to obtain the necessary $\beta \neq 0$.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You want $|f|$ above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f''(z)=0,$ we know $f(z)=\alpha+\beta z$. If $\beta=0,$ then $f(z)=\alpha.$ Think - can it be possible that $L|z|^{1/2}\leq |\alpha|$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}?$

Comment: You want $|\alpha|$ above.

Comment: Whoops, thanks!